# Конвертировать строку с закодированным UTF8 символов в символ кирилицы

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, utf-8, httpwebrequest

Из запроса http://ua-zip.net/script/suggest.php?prefix=61105&type=index я получаю ответ в виде:

> "\"1
>   \u0410\u0441\u043a\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0434\u0456\u0432\u0441\u044c\u043a\u0438\u0439".

Для отправки я использую:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(FullRequestString);
    request.Method = "GET";
```

Получаю ответ в конструкции:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
 {
  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
   {
   string line = "";
   while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
```

Каким образом мне преобразовать символы типа \u043b в кириллицу

Comment: Вы получаете JSON-ответ. Вам нужно десериализировать его (например, при помощи JSON.NET), и ваши строки будут такими, как надо. Пытаться разобрать JSON без парсера — глухой номер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сколько я знаю, .net не предоставляет готовой функции. Придется делать руками. Формат кодирования таков: сначала \u, потом четырехзначное шестнадцатиричное число, означающее код символа в кодировке UTF-8.

На скорую руку получилось вот такое решение.

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


var input = "\"\\\"1 \\u0410\\u0441\\u043a\\u043e\\u043b\\u044c\\u0434\\u0456\\u0432\\u0441\\u044c\\u043a\\u0438\\u0439\"";

var decoded = Decode(input, new CultureInfo("uk-UA"));


string Decode(string input, IFormatProvider provider)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input,
        @"\\u([0-9a-f]{4})",
        match => int.TryParse(match.Groups[1].Value,
            NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out var charCode)
                ? Convert.ToChar(charCode, provider).ToString()
                : match.Value);
}
```

С помощью регулярки находим в тексте все вхождения \uNNNN и для каждого из них вызываем Convert.ToChar(). Я не уверен, на сколько этот код эффективен в плане быстродействия, но в качестве примера пойдет.

И обратите внимание, что в переменной `input` я заэкранировал слеши. Если этого не сделать, то Visual Studio сама декодирует строку и ничего не получится протестировать.

Answer (score -3):

Как-то так.

```
string inputStr = "\u0410\u0441\u043a\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0434\u0456\u0432\u0441\u044c\u043a\u0438\u0439";
byte[] arrByte =  Encoding.Default.GetBytes(inputStr);
string result = Encoding.Default.GetString(arrByte);
```

result -> Аскольдівський

Comment: Ваш код, по сути, ничего не делает. Посмотрите на inputStr в отладчике - там уже лежит "Аскольдівський"

Comment: @PashaPash, возможно, но вопрос заключался в чём? Как из "\u043" получить кириллицу. Я это сделал, строка в понятной всем кодировке находится.

Comment: у топикастера в строке приходит именно `\u0410` - в коде на C# это или  `@"\u0410"`, или `"\\u0410"`. Т.е. ваш ответ подразумевает что топикастер возьмет респонс от сервера,  руками впишет его в исходник на C#, прогонит копмилятор (который и сделает всю работу), и потом зачем-то (зачем?) выполнит еще две строчи кода.  `GetBytes` и `GetString` - взаимо обратные операции. Ваш код действительно ничего не делает. Можно было бы написать `result = inputStr` - проблему топикастера это не решило бы - потому что в  inputStr  вы положили не ту строчку, которую получает топикастер. Проверьте в отладчике.

Comment: @PashaPash: «Ничего не делает» — это не вполне верно. Если русских символов нету в `Encoding.Default` (то есть, на системе с английской локалью, например), он либо бросает исключение, либо портит строку.